# Print the cards after calling the `get_cards()` method from `Deck` class

Tags: python

I am not able to print the cards after calling the `get_cards()` method from `Deck` class. I am new to Python. I thought by inheriting from the super `Deck` class, I would be able to print the cards in the `PlayerHand` class.

```
class Card(object):
      RANKS = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
         "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
      SUITS = ["Club", "Diamond", "Hearts", "Spades"]

      def __init__(self, rank, suit):
         self.suit = suit
         self.rank = rank

     def __str__(self):
         return self.suit + " of " + self.rank

 class Deck(object):
     def __init__(self):
     self.card = []

     def populate(self):
       for rank in Card.RANKS:
           for suite in Card.SUITS:
              self.card.append(Card(rank, suit))

     def get_cards(self):
           return self.card

     def shuffle(self):
        import random
        random.shuffle(self.card)

    class PlayerHand(Deck):

       def print_cards(self):
       cards = self.get_cards()
       for card in cards:
          print(i)

    if __name__=='__main__':
    player = PlayerHand()
    player.print_cards()
```

Comment: Is this your actual indentation?

Comment: No it's no my actual indentation. I think, it resorted when I was trying to format the code.

Comment: put code again and use button `{}` to correctly format code on SO.

Comment: Well, you initialize your `cards` as an empty list, so nothing would happen anyway.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since `i` isn't defined *anywhere*, why would you expect `print(i)` to do anything useful?

I think what you want is `print(card)`.

Comment: It still doesn't print after changing the i to card.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to print.  You initialized a Hand.  This inherits from Deck.  Initializing Deck does nothing except to set self.card to the empty list.  Thus, when you call **print_cards**, the hand is still empty.

Nothing in your code invokes any other method.  Creating an object does not automatically invoke your other methods.  You need to call **shuffle** and **populate** explicitly.

Most of all, though, you still have to put cards into the deck from which you're dealing.  You have to generate all 52 cards and put them into your master deck.

---

SIMPLE ADDITION:

```
class Deck(object):
     def __init__(self):
         print "Initialize deck"
         self.card = []
         self.populate()
         self.shuffle()
```

This turns your hand into a full deck of 52 cards, nicely shuffled.  If you make the other changes we've all recommended, it even prints out.

Comment: Thanks, You are right :). You were such a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @ScottHunter's answer, `i` doesn't mean anything.

In your iteration, you iterate each `Card` object in the `self.card` member in Deck.

Two problems in your code:

1. `seld.card` in Deck is not initialized. `populate` is never called and the cards have no value. You should call this function in the `__init__` of Deck.
2. In your iteration, `i` doesn't exist as I said. You should call print with card.rank (to get the value) or card.suit (or both), so it will be something like:

   ```
   print card # calls the __str__ method of card
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to populate the cards after initialize the player. That's player.card is empty and nothing will be printed. You should call player.populate() before calling function print_cards()

As others mentioned, i should be card. And I found a spelling mistake in populate function: 'suit' should be 'suite'

```
for suite in Card.SUITS:
    self.card.append(Card(rank, suit)) # should be suite
```

Comment: The error is the other way: change "suite" to "suit".